# Express.js SEO для SPA. Как отдавать страницу для поисковика

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

У меня есть SPA приложение. И мне нужно сделать СЕО для него, Next.js уже поздно использовать. Поэтому выбор пал на express.js Бэк у нас на Rest-api. Есть ли какой нибудь быстрый вариант прописать пути для страниц как в примере и отдавать это только поисковикам, а обычным пользователям показывать всё, что приходит с реакта?

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```

Суть в том, что я хочу заполнять пустой index.html мета теги и наполнение сайта по разным линкам через запросы rest api

Comment: С чего бы Next поздно использовать?) Но вообще статей для самостоятельного накручивания SSR достаточно: https://habr.com/ru/articles/551948/ , https://dev.to/juhanakristian/basics-of-react-server-side-rendering-with-expressjs-phd , https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-server-side-rendering

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Просто проект большой вышел, и прокидывать все по новой можно с ума сойти, а времени столько не будет. А ссылки я уже видел, и там примеры как делать SSR когда начинаешь проект делать с нуля, но мне просто нужно отдавать информацию для поисковиков, а пользователю оставить всё как есть

Comment: Ну а как вы хотели? Чтобы вжух и всё по магии работало?) Так не получится, под SSR придётся хоть немного перепилить (хотя по статьям вообще не много чего делать надо, гидратировать приложение через встроенную. функцию и на бэке рендерить).

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Ну да хотелось бы легких решений, сейчас попробовал сделать через HydrateRoot обернуть с подключенным экспрессом, но проблема в том что App в index.js у меня обернут в Redux, Browser Router и пару ContextApi